# Prevent GTK elements from resizing parents?

Tags: gtk, rust

I have been struggling with an issue with Gtk for numerous hours now.
I have a ListBox element with ListBoxRows, with ListBoxLabels inside.

```
let list_item = gtk::ListBoxRow::new();
list_item.set_size_request(600, 200);
list_item.set_resize_mode(gtk::ResizeMode::Parent);

let content_label = gtk::Label::new_with_mnemonic(rant["text"].as_string());
// content_label.set_halign(gtk::Align::Start);
// content_label.set_valign(gtk::Align::Start);
content_label.set_justify(gtk::Justification::Left);
content_label.set_line_wrap(true);
content_label.set_size_request(200, 200);

list_item.add(&content_label);

container.insert(&list_item, -1);
```

However, when the app runs, the Labels are resizing all of it's parent elements. It ignores any size_request, line_wrap, Justification. Nothing I throw at it will prevent it from resizing it's parent element.

How can I prevent the parent/window from resizing and force those elements to be of a specific width?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to tell the parent element not to resize, but I did manage to find a way to prevent it from resizing.

The key was to call

```
widget.show_all();
```

Before adding widgets to it. Then after showing the window, in the function body call

```
container.show_all();
```

At the end of the function.

It may not be the 'correct' solution, but it worked for me for the time being.